# Intel 5100 AGN disconnects and then disables my Verizon FiOS Actiontec router

Tags: intel-wireless

I am a new user (my first trial) of Ubuntu and booted up my Windows Vista laptop up with the Ubuntu CD. I was able to connect wirelessly to my router and stay connected for about a minute. After that it would disconnect and my router would be disabled: none of my other wireless devices would see the signal any longer, as if it disappeared. I would have to cycle the router's power toggle off/on to get it to come back on and put out a signal again. This happened repeatedly.

I experienced no other problems trying the software (i.e., accessed my files w/o issue). I did not attempt to connect with an Ethernet cable.

Here are the specs on my system:

- laptop is HP Pavilion dv5 Notebook PC
- system type is 64-bit operating system
- CPU is Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 2.4GHz
- ram is 4 GB
- network card is Intel WiFi Link 5100 AGN

I read elsewhere in this forum that 64-bit systems may not be compatible with Ubuntu. Can anyone help me with this? I'd really like to be able to use this op system.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, Ubuntu definitely does support 64 bit computers. They have 32 and 64 bit versions and either will work fine on a 64 bit computer. As for your wifi, it appears that many people have had similar problems with it in both Windows and Linux.  http://communities.intel.com/thread/19218  Does your wifi work better in Windows? One solution may be to use a usb wifi adapter instead of the onboard one.